# Why is there a function within a function in React documentation?

Tags: reactjs, function, event-handling

I was reading the documentation to React about handling events and was confused about why there is a handleSubmit within a Form function

```
function Form() {
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('You clicked submit.');
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Why is function Form() needed for the explanation about React's event handlers? If someone can give a little more detail about their reason that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What do you think is wrong if you use `function inside function`? `Form` is react component, and `handleSubmit` is event handler.

Comment: I guess what gets me confused is why is the handleSubmit function inside Form function? Wouldn't handleSubmit() still work even without Form().

Comment: It can be outside, is correct. But this is a simple example. In real usages in the handleSubmit you will need to do something extra, with the state or props, so you will need to be inside the Form function. Also I think is better to keep the functions inside the component to keep it encapsulated. Think in the Form as the Component, and the functions inside are what defines the component behavior.

Comment: "Form as the Component"!!! Gotcha! Now I understand. Thanks @DanielSifontes for the explanation.